# jwplayer External Play Pause Button

Tags: javascript, jwplayer

I want to add a play and pause button outside the player.

I added `onclick="jwplayer().play();"` to the page.
But this doesn't work

Is there any way?

Answer (score 1):

If the player is not playing, then your code should work. Can you provide the entire code example?

From their documentation at https://developer.jwplayer.com/jw-player/docs/javascript-api-reference/ , calling `jwplayer().play()` when the player is already playing does nothing. Have you tried `jwplayer().pause()` ?